# Visual Studio Code - automatic closing HTML tags

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I am working with Visual Studio Code and I am looking for an extension to close automatically the HTML tags. I know that Sublime has this feature but I was wondering if it is possible in VSC. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a package called 'auto close tag' here:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag

Answer (score 0):

[Auto Close Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag) by Jun Han is what you are searching for